# How do I get my files from google vm disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My google vm crashed and I cannot access my files. The disk is still available, but cannot be used to create another instance.

Many attempts to create another instance with that disk were successful, but still I cannot access the instance with ssh, which renders the instance worthless.

Now I created another instance with a new disk, How can I access my files on the old disk, either by mounting it on the new instance?

I have tried also make it additional persistent disk on a new vm, which I believe went fine, but still I don't know how to access my files on the old disk. including my mariadb database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you will have to attach your old disk to a new GCE instance and then mount it to access it with the following command:

$ sudo mount [/PATH/TO/DISK] [/MOUNT/PATH]

Keep in mind that if you are not able to mount the disk could be because the file system is damaged.